# Is it possible to pass data other than string or list as argument for a subprocess in python?

Tags: python, subprocess

I can start a sub-process with a list as arguments for example like this:

```
data = []
data.append("test")
subprocess.run(['python', 'myprocess.py'] + data)
```

My question is, if it is possible to pass bigger amounts of data to the sub-process? For example, if I have loaded a bunch of images and want to pass them directly as numpy arrays without having to store them to file and pass the paths as strings to load them again in the sub-process?

Comment: Instead of using a subprocess you could add the myprocess.py file to your path. import it as a module, and run the function with the required data as variable parameters. Sub process is just the same as running a command line argument anyway from what I understand.

Comment: @JacobBotha yep, that would be possible. However, I need the two parts to be independent from one another, hence the subprocess.

Comment: Pass your data to the subprocess via stdin -- that's the conventional Right Thing.

Comment: ...or, if you want something fancier, `multiprocessing` has shared-memory approaches and other options.

Comment: ...though _why_ you need them to be independent is a question worth asking -- in some cases, you may be able to just `fork()` with no `execve()`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy tbh First day at new work, I was just told to do it as a subprocess :) I guess, to be flexible but I don't know for sure

Comment: `fork()` creates subprocesses. `multiprocessing` creates subprocesses. The `subprocess` module isn't the only way to get a subprocess -- it's just the _best_ one if you want an `execve()`, but if your goal is to have data be immediately available to the new process, maybe you _don't want_ an `execve()`.

Comment: (Background: In the traditional UNIX way of doing things, starting a subprocess has two steps: `fork()` to make a new process that's _exactly identical to the old one_ except for the return value received by the `fork()` call; and then `execve()` to replace the new process with a different executable image -- but there's no law that says you can't `fork()` without `execve()` to get a new process that's a duplicate of your old one, or call `exece()` without `fork()`ing to replace your current executable with a different one having the same PID).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, very helpful information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argument vectors are arrays of C strings at the operating system level (see `man execve`). You can only pass data on the argv that can be represented as a C string (note that C strings are NUL-terminated, so no NULs allowed). You can certainly serialize data into a C string on one side and deserialize it on the other side, but that's work.

Moreover, there's a maximum amount of storage available that's shared between environment variables and command-line arguments -- so the more/larger environment variables you have, the shorter the combined length of all your command-line arguments can be.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. The `subprocess` module is only a wrapper around the system call used to create a process and pass it a **command line**. In most system, that command line is just a sequence of space separated words, hence the list of strings.

If you want to pass anything else, you will have to serialize the data on one side, pass it from one process to the other one through pipes or shared memory (if available) or environment variables and deserialize it in the second process. `pickle` can be an easy tool to serialize simple data.

Alternatively, you could have a look at the `multiprocess` modules that does those things under the hood between Python processes

Comment: Only on Windows are spaces passed between process to indicate argument boundaries -- in the civilized world, we pass an array of strings; anything like quotes and spaces to indicate boundaries was already removed before that array was constructed. The "command line" as a single string is, in the UNIX world, an abstraction that doesn't really exist at the C level -- even calling `system("something here")` is eventually going to become `execv("/bin/sh", char[][]{"sh", "-c", "something here", NULL}`

Comment: (...after which that copy of `sh` will do something like `execv("/usr/bin/something", char[][]{"something", "here", NUL})`; so thinking in terms of argument vectors is much more useful than thinking in terms of command lines to understand what's happening under the hood)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy From a *user* point of view, command arguments are separated with spaces. It does matter for complex arguments that should contain spaces or special characters, because Unix conventions are far more powerful than Windows ones. But for a beginner handling *simple* arguments both systems seems rather close to each other.